# How to delete a corrupted directory, can't see the inode

Tags: filesystem, directory, inode

"Something happened" many months ago and a folder was corrupted. I want to delete that folder - or rather, I want to remove the inode that points to the space that was assigned to that folder. I don't think there is any data there, so there's nothing to lose.

Note that the inode cannot be found with ls and 'i' option.

```
2590623 drwxrwxr-- 744 web15 client1 36864 Jun 28 00:18 .
2590617 drwxr-xr-x  18 root  root     4096 Mar 28 17:30 ..
2603401 drwx------   2 web15 client1  4096 May 20  2021 .mount_CollabDCMBh4
2623352 drwx------   2 web15 client1  4096 Mar 30 15:00 .mount_CollabKq1DUR
      ? d?????????   ? ?     ?           ?            ? .mount_CollabN9npNy
4644867 drwx------   2 web15 client1  4096 Jun 21 14:55 .mount_CollabS8Qf2G
3106436 drwx------   2 web15 client1  4096 Jul 16  2021 .mount_CollabUw4Eed
```

I am very adverse to any brute force method to remove the folder with rm or a similar command that operates on the file system of a folder. Since this looks seriously corrupted, I don't want to take the chance that the hidden inode points to some valid location, and a remove command may blindly follow that path to delete something completely unrelated to this. That is, if whatever that data is can be coerced into an integer, I don't want rm to attempt a delete operation at whatever is located at that address.

So I'd prefer to delete the inode itself so that this current folder doesn't see it.

In this specific scenario, the folder shown above is a /var/www/sites/.../tmp folder, and I have no problem deleting everything in that folder. I do have the inode ID for the tmp folder itself. So I can use rm to remove everything else in tmp, then remove the inode for tmp, the parent folder, and that eliminates the visibility of the child folder.

But I wanted to toss this to the audience here, to see if there is a way to get more info on this part of the file system so that a more surgical operation can be performed. I believe an operation could be done on the volume if it's not mounted, but this system is hosting websites so I'd prefer to keep it up.

Comment: What about running fsck?

Comment: Manual manipulation of inodes hasn't been a Good Idea since the 1970s, when disk caching began. Use `fsck` on an unmounted disk. Read `man fsck`.

Comment: When a disk is mounted, the actual, real true inode may be in the filesystem memory, the filesystem's inode cache, in the disk inode cache or on the disk. The kernel keeps track of which one is current. A modified inode in the filesystem's memory will, over time, migrate through all the caches, eventually to disk. Only when a disk (all of its partitions) is unmounted (`umount`) are the on-disk inodes guaranteed to be up-to-date.

Comment: If you don't have a recurring, dedicated window when you can perform `fsck` and other antisocial tasks, you're not a good System Administrator. Also, you seem to be willing to do inode surgery on a live production server, which is a Well Known Bad Idea. When, not if, it crashes, do the `fsck`.

Comment: @waltinator We're obviously on the same page about the odd and dangerous nature of this issue - thanks for that. I did say "I'd prefer to keep it up", not that I can't take it down or that fsck is off the table. Let's back up a little. Do you have any more ideas or insight into the nature of a problem like this? Do you agree that removing the inode is the right resolution? Thanks.